# webpage appearing only when hitting refresh

Tags: web, error-handling, refresh, lamp

My website [www.999designs.in](http://999designs.in) won't open at once, it shows an error, however it works fine once you refresh it!!
 I've hosted it on a `LAMP` environment, does it require any specific server settings??

First it given an error "Can not find the page you're looking for".

Comment: Is the server it hosted on Load Balanced, if so you may want to check the Host Headers on the Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of the problem is that you initialize the slider with a wrong image file name. Have a look at function.js line 240:

```
$(['img/woman1.png','img/woman2.png','img/woman3.png']).preload();
```

If you reload the image for "banner-slide-woman-1" is called *woman.png* not *woman1.png*.

HTH
Andy